# Annotation Difficulty in PCA with numpy and matplotlib

Tags: python, django, numpy, matplotlib, pca

I'm trying to do PCA analysis for our Repertory Grid Tool. I have a matrix which contains all the info I need, however I want to put the names of the alternatives(column names) on the dots in the analysis. My code is something like this:

```
matrixAlternatives= transpose(matrixAlternatives)
var_grid = np.array(matrixAlternatives)
#improve output readability
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

print "var_grid:"
print var_grid

#Create the PCA node and train it
pcan = mdp.nodes.PCANode(output_dim=2, svd=True)
pcar = pcan.execute(var_grid)
print "\npcar"
print pcar

print "\neigenvalues:"
print pcan.d

print "\nexplained variance:"
print pcan.explained_variance

print "\neigenvectors:"
print pcan.v

#Graph results
#pcar[3,0],pcar[3,1] has the projections of alternative3 on the
#first two principal components (0 and 1)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(pcar[:, 0], pcar[:, 1], 'r^')
ax.plot(pcan.v[:,0], pcan.v[:,1], 'ro')

#draw axes
ax.axhline(0, color='black')
ax.axvline(0, color='black')

#annotations each concern
id=0
for xpoint, ypoint in pcan.v:
ax.annotate('C{:.0f}'.format(id), (xpoint, ypoint), ha='center',
va='center', bbox=dict(fc='white',ec='none'))
id+=1


#calculate accounted for variance
var_accounted_PC1 = pcan.d[0] * pcan.explained_variance * 100 /(pcan.d[0] + pcan.d[1])
var_accounted_PC2 = pcan.d[1] * pcan.explained_variance * 100 /(pcan.d[0] + pcan.d[1])

#Show variance accounted for
ax.set_xlabel('Accounted variance on PC1 (%.1f%%)' % (var_accounted_PC1))
ax.set_ylabel('Accounted variance on PC2 (%.1f%%)' % (var_accounted_PC2))

canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')

canvas.print_png(response)
fig.clf()
plt.close()
plt.clf()
del var_grid
gc.collect()
return response
```

Comment: You will get better answers if you have a minimum working example of the problem. Is the PCA stuff really relevant? Seems you just want to know how to annotate data in a plot, in which case you could cut the code here down to plotting a few simple randomly generated sets of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you just need to annotate your plots using the column heading. Here is a minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10 ,100)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x, y , "ro")
plt.annotate(s=" some string", xy=(x[25], y[25]))
```

[image: example]

You will need to add some formatting I suspect to get the strings in the correct place.

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to annote them while pointing? For example I have 8 things to point in the graph and I have the names of them in an array let's say. Can I do it automatically?

Comment: By pointing I presume you mean something like an arrow? If so then [this guide should help](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html). To automate this I would define a function that accepts the position and text then just loop over the points.